# opencv_python-3.4.2+contrib-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python-3.x

while trying to install the wheel file I'm getting the not a supported wheel on this platform and also updated pip

opencv_python-3.4.2+contrib-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Comment: what version of python do you have? what is your OS? 64bit or 32bit?

Comment: the problem was solved and windows 10, 64bit , python 3.7

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

This will install it via pip.  And it is way easier to do. 
I am running python 3.5 for this inside anaconda. Install with no issues.
Please note you can only have one version installed at a time on each environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not just an `opencv` + `poetry` issue. It's effected me with several other packages too.

The underlying cause is the `pip` version according to [python-poetry issue 5104](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5104). So `pip install -U pip` should fix it. You could also upgrade Poetry (`poetry self update`) I went from `^1.3` to `^1.4` without the pip upgrade and I got a warning, not an error, but with the pip upgrade there was no errors or warnings.

@MNM's suggestion will work, but if you're using Poetry I presume proper dependency resolution is important to you. If you just run `pip install x` you bypass Poetry's dependancy resolution and `pip` will simply install package `x` and all its dependencies over the top what what Poetry has already installed.

---

Real talk time: *I know poetry's dependency resolution can be a little time consuming. I have been known to `pip install x` just to keep moving, then at lunch I'll run the `poetry add x` so `poetry` can sort its life out while I'm enjoying a hard earned <strike>coffee</strike> beer.*